# How do I add more whitespace between my posts on Blogger?

Tags: blogger, blogger-templates

See picture which is a screen shot of my blog. I simply want to add more space in between my posts. As it stands right now there is the same amount of space between the end of the last post and the date which corresponds to the new post.

I want to put more space where the yellow arrow is my image below. How do I do that?

[image: my blog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **theme** > **Customize** > **Advanced** > **Add CSS**

```
.main-inner .date-outer {
    margin-bottom: 7em;
}
```

Comment: Holy cow that worked beautifully.  Can you explain to me how you were able to come up with that?

Comment: Using CSS margin property you can create space around HTML elements [read more](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)